# Using Formula Language to return column values

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs, lotus, lotus-formula

I'm trying to return all values stored in the tNames variable.

Values exists in the field. The show multivalues as separate entries have been selected already but none of the names is returned.

Below is the sample code:

```
tNames := "";
@For(n := 0; n <= QuestionCount - 1; n := n + 1;
tNames := tNames + ", " + @Implode(@GetField("ChecklistContact_" + 
  @Text(n));",")
);
@Trim(tNames)
```

I dont know why its not returning anything, will appreciate your help.

The below returns only the contact with index 0, but I want to return all contacts in each document.

```
tCount := 0;
@For(n := 0; n <= QuestionCount - 1; n := n + 1;
 tCount := tCount + @If(@GetField("ChecklistContact_" + @Text(n)) = ""; 0; 1)
);
@GetField("ChecklistContact_" + @Text(tCount))
```

Following comments from Richard the below return the required values, but will prefer not to hard code field name.

Is there any way of using for loop to return field names and values?

```
tNames := "";
tNames:= @GetField("ChecklistContact_1") : @GetField("ChecklistContact_2") : ... @GetField("ChecklistContact_7");
@Trim(tNames)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that [IBM's documentatio](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/de/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETFIELD.html)n says this explicitly, but I don't think @GetField works in column value formulas. The doc says that it works in the "current document", and there is no current document when the formula is executing in a view.

Assuming you know what the maximum number for N is, the way to do this is with a simple list:

```
ChecklistContact_1 : ChecklistContact_2 : ChecklistContact_3 : ... : ChecklistContact_N
```

If N is large, this will be a lot of typing, but you'll only have to do it once and copying and pasting and editing the numbers will make it go pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've added a new script above that returns only the first index using the @GetField(), but I'll like to return all.

Comment: I've added script above that returns all required values, but I will like not to hard code field names. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can add a computed field to the form(s) for the documents in the view, as shillem suggested. Your looping strategy with get field will work there. But you will have to refresh and resave all documents before you see the results from that at the view level.If there are a lot of documents and users have replicas, they will take a hit. Unread marks will be changed, too.  Also, make sure the check box for multi-values is selected in the computed field. That is the only way I can think of to avoid hard-coding.

Answer (score 2):

It might sound inelegant but, if you can, create a new computed field with your column formula in your form and then use that new field in your column. Also, from a performance standpoint you will be better off.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use your loop to create the list of fieldnames as Richard suggested, then display tNames

Comment: I don't believe that's possible. AFAIK, there is no way to access field values in a column formula other than by referencing the field by hard-coded name.